# MPDF always gives 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: mpdf

I've looked at multiple tutorials on the matter and apparently MPDF is a simple as can be.

```
<?php 
  require_once('tools/mpdf.php');
  $mpdf = new mPDF();
  $mpdf->WriteHTML('<p>Your first taste of creating PDF from HTML</p>');

  $mpdf->Output();
  exit;
?>
```

Obviously I'm going to build on top of this but I can't even get the basics working for some reason. All I get is a "500 Internal Server Error". I've stripped the file down to just

```
<?php 
  require_once('tools/mpdf.php');
?>
```

And I get that error. I've ensured that the mpdf.php file is in the tools directory and properly loaded onto my server, so there's no issue there..

Any ideas?

Comment: I would recommend turning up the error message level to see what the error message is. error_reporting(E_ALL) should do it. Post the output in your question for further clarification.

Comment: Adding that error_reporting snippet doesn't change anything..

Comment: There is no output to post. Just a 500-error.

Comment: Are you using Apache? maybe check the apache error logs?

Comment: Even if this is a 5 years old question, just for others that may follow the hints in the comments: setting `error_reporting(E_ALL);` will always output an "HTTP Error 500" page in case displaying errors is disabled which it is on a default installation. When debugging, also set `ini_set("display_errors", "1");` to show errors, notifications etc.. Changing ini_settings may be disabled so check the result value of `ini_set()` if is was FALSE (current PHP version) or "" for a pre 5.3 version which would mean it failed changing.

Answer (score 7):

I was having this issue and found a simple solution. Mpdf worked well on my local machine but I had the trouble when using it on a remote server.

If anyone else is having the same issue when deploying your app on a remote server.

1. Check your server error log
2. If you see an error like this `"Exceptioncaught Mpdf\\MpdfException: Temporary files directory.... is not writeable"`
3. You may try to change the permission of the mpdf/tmp folder example: `chmod 777 /vendor/mpdf/mpdf/tmp`, which I do not recommend because it would give read, write and execute permission to the owner, group and public
4. The best approach is to check the owner of the directory and assign it to your web server if you are using apache, example: `chown www:www /vendor/mpdf/mpdf/tmp`

It worked for me, I hope it can help others.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I was desperate in the end but I deleted tmp sub-folder from mpdf folder and it started working.